# Getting this errors in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

> ### A PHP Error was encountered
>
> **Severity:** Warning
>
> **Message:** `in_array()` expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given
>
> **Filename:** models/main_model.php
>
> **Line Number:** 1386

and line number 1386 is :

```
$pcode_id=$this->get_postcode_id($value);
$myarr=unserialize($in_search);
if(in_array($pcode_id,$myarr)) // line 1386
{
    return $myarr;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

The result still shows but the error appears.

Comment: and what part of the error message are you not getting? your $myarr is a boolean when the function expects an array argument. So pass an array instead.

Comment: That akward moment when people have to repeat the same thing that the error generated by PHP says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently $myarr is not an array at some point... you could var_dump($myarr); and run your code and see at what point it is not an array.

But you should check first if $myarr is an array before trying in_array.

```
if (is_array($myarr) && in_array($pcode_id, $myarr)) {
  return $myarr;
}
else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks your answer was along the lines of my correction.

Answer (score 0):

Your `myarr` variable is not an array. That means the string you are throwing in the `unserialize` method isn't actually a `serialized array`

Comment: myarr sometimes is passed as an array as the form sends either one or multiple values hence why it is serialized. but your answer helped point me in the right direction.